# Is there a faster for me to look to a specific index without using an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine, optimization

I'm creating kind of a 2D map where which coord has a `tile` class attached to it,
The `tile` class would have its coord inside of it, and some other values that would be accessed later, but I would like to have that map with no size limitations. The problem is, I want to see the values inside of some `tile` in that map, for example: I'm at coord(25,30) and I want to know a bool value inside the `tile` class in each adjacent `tile`.

- And if I use an array, I would have maybe the fastest way to check the coord of a `tile`, e.g. an array of 2 indexes. I could make each index be a x and a y coord respectively, so I would only check that coord when seeing the values on a `tile`. **But the map would have a limit in size**.
- And if I use a list **the map won't have a limit in size** but I can't check the coordinate directly, so I would need to go through each created `tile` with a `foreach` loop, and check if the coord inside that tile, is the same as the one I am looking for.
- My current solution is to have a second List with only the coordinates, and have it assigned when I create a tile, so the index in the coordinate list is the same as in the tile list. So when I need to check for a tile, I do a `CoordinateList.Contains(coordinate)`, and if that is true, then I put the index of that coordinate as the index that the code should look in the `tile` List.

**I want a faster way to check a tile, without a size limitation.**

> So far, with the `tile` List I got around 3200ms for each time I checked the whole map (about 2000 `tiles` in the list).
>
> And with the `mapCoord` List I got around 1500ms (around 2000 tiles and coords).
>
> And with the array I was getting a pretty fast response (never measured it) but less than I second for sure... Since I never had to check for the whole Array, but one for a certain index.

### Examples for easier understanding of my problem:

> note1: It does not fill all the array.
>
> note2: It wouldn't always be rectangular.

```
int size = 50;
Tile[,] mapArray = new Tile[size,size];
List<Tile> mapList = new List<Tile>();
List<Vector2Int> mapCoord = new List<Vector2Int>();
void CreateMap()
{
    for(int x = size/2; size <= size/2; x++)
    {
        for(int y = size/2; size <= size/2; y++)
        {
        if(x > 2 && y > 3)
            {
            mapArray[x,y] = new Tile(new Vector2Int(x,y), false, 32);
            mapList.add(new Tile(new Vector2Int(x,y), false, 32));
            mapCoord.add(new Vector2Int(x,y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if I was to check a `tile` in the array, in the array I would just check the coord, since the `tile` coord would be the same as the array index, but it would have a size limit.

And if I was to check the tile in the list, I would need to do a `foreach` loop like this. Pretty bad for performance and optimization.

```
Tile desiredTile = null;
for each(Tile tile in mapTiles)
{
    if(tile.Coord == DesiredCoord)
        desiredTile = tile;
}
```

And the best way so far, is checking the `mapCoord` list like this:

```
if(mapCoord.Contains(desiredCoord))
{
    desiredTile = mapList[mapCoord.IndexOf(DesiredCoord)];
}
```

Comment: Is `size <= size/2` **ever** going to be `true`? Check your loop conditions.

Comment: Look up "sparse array" as a way to do this. One possible implementation is a Dictionary where the key is effectively a tuple of two ints (x and y). If the game starts with a standard boundary (say +/- 100 of the starting point) you could mix and match, a 200x200 array and the dictionary beyond that. You can also get creative by having multiple rectangular regions, each as an array.

Comment: @spender it was a type, it was meant to be x = -size/2 not the positive, same for the y

Comment: @Flydog57 the Dictionary really did it for me, got from 1500ms, to almost 10ms, really good idea from you, thx a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Look up "sparse array" as a way to do this. One possible implementation is a Dictionary where the key is effectively a tuple of two ints (x and y). If the game starts with a standard boundary (say +/- 100 of the starting point) you could mix and match, a 200x200 array and the dictionary beyond that. You can also get creative by having multiple rectangular regions, each as an array.

If your total address space fits into a short integer (+/- 32k), then you could do something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct IntXY
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] Int16 X;
    [FieldOffset(2)] Int16 Y;
    [FieldOffset(0)] UInt32 AsAnUnsignedInteger;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return AsAnUnsignedInteger.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and use that as the key in your Dictionary (using `LayoutKind.Explicit` makes this is effectively the same as a C/C++ `union` - the X and Y shorts take up the same combined 32 bits as the unsigned int).  It's probably cheaper than a `Tuple<int, int>` (though you'd probably want to test my guess).